# Queueing positions for the robot to move to

Tags: ros, queue

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I would like to have the robot move to point a->b->c in order and am not sure how to do this using a simple action client. I'm using movebase for this. When I add a second position for the robot to move to then it overwrites the first position. Thus, it looks like I need a way to check what the robot's current position is and if it point a then the robot should move to b and so on. Is this correct? How would I go about implementing this?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211719/queueing-positions-for-the-robot-to-move-to/) by [duskxii](https://answers.ros.org/users/22567/duskxii/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-06-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can listen `/move_base/status` for the status of the current goal. [Here](http://wiki.ros.org/move_base#Action_API) is the related document. You can go on with your second goal only if the first one is successful, for example.

Moreover, if you want to try a systematic approach you can use [smach](http://wiki.ros.org/smach) to create a state machine with states and transitions etc.

---

Originally posted by [yigit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2389/yigit/) with karma: 796 on 2015-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1